# push notifications configuration parse Bitnami API on AWS dosent work

Tags: amazon-web-services, parsing, push-notification, bitnami

I have a problem with the enabling of push notifications for my Parse server for iOS Apps. I followed all the steps on the official Parse website for enabling these push notification but I get the error code: parseError { code: 115, message: 'Missing push configuration' }. Here is my Code from the server.js file.
I edit this in server.js in /apps/parse/htdocs

```
express = require('express');
var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;
var app = express();
// Specify the connection string for your mongodb database
// and the location to your Parse cloud code 
var api = new ParseServer({
databaseURI: "mongodb://root:XXXXXXXXXXXXXX7/bitnami_parse",
cloud: "./node_modules/parse-server/lib/cloud-code/Parse.Cloud.js",
appId: "1XXXXXXXXXXXd",
masterKey: "eXXXXXXXXXXXXXX8",
fileKey: "8XXXXXXXXXXXX0",
serverURL: "http://1XXXXXXXXXXX0/parse",
push: {
android: {
senderId: '',
apiKey: ''
},
ios: {
pfx: '/home/bitnami/pushNotificationStudyPlay.p12',
passphrase: '', // optional password to your p12/PFX
bundleId: 'StudXXXXXXXXlay',
production: false
}
}
});
// Serve the Parse API on the /parse URL prefix
app.use('/parse', api);

var port = 1337;
app.listen(port, function() {
console.log('parse-server running on port ' + port);
});

//Parse Dashboard
var ParseDashboard = require('parse-dashboard');
var dashboard = new ParseDashboard({
apps: [
{
appName: "My Bitnami Parse API",
appId: "1XXXXXXXXXXXXXd",
masterKey: "eXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX8",
fileKey: "8XXXXXXXXXXXXX0",
production: true,
serverURL: "http://1XXXXXXXXX0/parse"
}
],
users: [
{
user: "AXXXXXXXn",
pass: "$2XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXC"
}
], useEncryptedPasswords: true
});

var allowInsecureHTTP = true;

// Serve the Parse Dashboard on the /parsedashboard URL prefix
app.use('/', dashboard);

var portdash = 4XX0;
app.listen(portdash, function() {
console.log('parse-dashboard running on port ' + portdash);
});
```